# Changed resource image with another, recompiled, but the old image still appears

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-resources

Did anyone face such a situation: you change a resource image with another image of the same name (for ex, btn.png with other btn.png), you then recompile the project and load the app into a mobile phone or emulator, but the **old image still appears**?

I do not know how to solve this issue. I tried uninstalling the app from the device, and installing the changed one, but new image still does not appear.

I know that I can choose a new filename and it will work, but how to force resource rebuilding?

PS. I realized that you can rebuild the project manually, so if anyone has a better solution (and faster), please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that in case when you replace one image with another of the same name, you **have to rebuild the project** as it will only trigger resources rebuilt.

I've tested different ways, and project rebuild was the only command which remapped PNG files in the resources folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem.Try doing all these this

1. 1.Checkout all the resource folders and make sure the earlier image does not exist in any of the folders.

   2.Try checking the name of the new image and check weather is same as to that of the earlier ones.

   3.Try uninstalling the app after clearing all the data from the emulator or phone. Hope making all these stuff sure will solve this problem.I got it ryt by doing all these.

   4.Also try runing the project after clearing the bin and gen folder in your project

.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image in the resource folder is replaced by new image . In that case it must show new image after you do a clean build.